# Change webapp directory of nb project

Tags: java, web-applications, netbeans, maven, netbeans-7

I cannot change a webapp directory of my maven project in NetBeans. I would like to that IDE links its Web Pages to other location than `main/webapp/`.

How can I set `web.dir` in this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just configure the war plugin accordingly. Specifically the warSourceDirectory property.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html